# R package: description and importFrom namespace files

Tags: r, import, package

I'm having some issues towards a package that I'm building (RadTran) that uses functions from another package ReacTran (setup.grid.1D, setup.grid.2D, setup.prop.2D, tran.2D and steady.2D).

When I run the R check command on the package, everything seems alright but at the end when the examples are checked, an error occurs. It seems that the function that I've build in my RadTran package "cannot be found".

I think that this is linked with the packages definition in the description file and in the namespace file.

In the namespacefile I'm using "importFrom(package, function)":

```
importFrom(ReacTran,setup.grid.1D)
importFrom(ReacTran,setup.grid.2D)
importFrom(ReacTran,setup.prop.2D)
importFrom(ReacTran,tran.2D)
importFrom(rootSolve,steady.2D)
```

*rootSolve is another package inside ReacTran for the function steady.2D

And in the description file I have:

```
Depends: R (>= 2.10), ReacTran
Imports: rootSolve
License: GPL-2
```

When running the example I'm using the basic "require(RadTran)" at the beginning.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "an error occurs" - aha. Give error messages always verbatim. Did you export your function?

Comment: Hi, the error that I get is: could not find function "RnDif.het" - execution halted. I did not export the function!

Comment: Well, then export it. Only exported functions should be used in examples.

Comment: Yes, it's done now. Thank you friend!